# How to solve error in VS Code - exited with code=127

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Baffled by this. I've been using VSCode for a few weeks and have python installed.

```
def print menu():
    print ("Let's play a game of Wordle!")
    print ("Please type in a 5-letter word") 
        print_menu()
print_menu()
```

So far so simple, but when I run it I get this

[Running] python -u "/Users/davidelks/Dropbox/Personal/worldle.py"
/bin/sh: python: command not found

[Done] exited with code=127 in 0.006 seconds

What does this mean? I'm guessing it failed but why? This appears to be trivial.

UPDATE:

Tried:

```
def print menu():
        print ("Let's play a game of Wordle!")
        print ("Please type in a 5-letter word") 
        
    print_menu()
```

It failed.

Comment: `def print menu()` -> `def print_menu()`

Comment: It means your computer did not recognize the command `python`.  Either it was installed as some other name (perhaps `python3`), or the installation process did not add it to your PATH.  (Or, possibly, it did, but you need to reboot...)

Comment: _and have python installed_ How, exactly, did you install it?

Comment: John Gordon, yes I did.It's just not working and I don't have an option to remove and then reimport. Instead I get disable which is not what I want.

Comment: Yash Mehta
I've had python installed and

Comment: John It was working even earlier today but just kicked on that error on a new program.

Comment: recursively calling `print_menu()` from within `print_menu()` without an exit condition like this will lead to a stack overflow.

Comment: @JonSQ I dropped the print_menu in the function but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I ran the code using python3 from my terminal and it executes fine.

The issue is that you are using a binary that doesn't exist in /bin folder. (`python` in this case.)

Trying issuing just `python` and `python3` respectively, with no options and see which ones returns a command not found error.

Moreover, python version 2 (meaning, command `python` is deprecated), see: https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/

You have to use python3, so for your case:

```
python3 -u /Users/davidelks/Dropbox/Personal/worldle.py
```

This is the code that I ran:

```
def print_menu():
    print ("Let's play a game of Wordle!")
    print ("Please type in a 5-letter word") 

print_menu()
```

Then, saved it as `python.py` and opened it from the directory:

```
user@localhost:~/Documents/test-realm $ python3 ./python.py 
Let's play a game of Wordle!
Please type in a 5-letter word
user@localhost:~/Documents/test-realm $ python3 python.py
Let's play a game of Wordle!
Please type in a 5-letter word
user@localhost:~/Documents/test-realm $
```

Answer (score 1):

> [Running] python -u "/Users/davidelks/Dropbox/Personal/worldle.py" /bin/sh: python: command not found

This error means that Python is not installed or your installation is corrupted.

You can enter python in the terminal to check whether the system can correctly identify python environment variables. You can also try reinstalling python.

Answer (score 0):

Try to end your filename with (.py) or try reloading the python extension.

Comment: I've done that. How do I reload the python extension?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try entering the VSCode command. On linux, you can digital control + shift + P.

In the dialog that appears at the top, type:
select python interpreter.

Select option:
Python: select interpreter

After that, select the python interpreter you intend to use with your VSCode and see if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but after a few attempts it was enough to select: run the file in python to get everything back to working properly. I apologize for the Italian texts of my vsc[image]

Answer (score 0):

Run your code through "Run Python File." It will be fixed. For clear view, see the image.
[see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7KCj.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Posting images of solutions is discouraged for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2530121). Please update your answer to include all relevant information as text to complement your answer - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35714089)